# Class Rectangle not recognised

Tags: java, rectangles

Below is part of some code that draws rectangles (WIDTH is set to an integer variable)

```
 int x = j*WIDTH;
 int y = i*WIDTH;
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, WIDTH - 1, WIDTH - 1);
```

For some reason on BlueJ I get cannot find symbol - class Rectangle. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you `import java.awt.Rectangle`?

Comment: Thanks! Forget about that

Answer (score 0):

`Import` Java.awt.Rectangle. That should do the trick. 
EDIT: didn't notice somebody answered in a comment. Sorry..